# How to strip apostrophe from pandas column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to remove an apostrophe from a column name in my pandas df. The column name is something like `Parents' favorite color`

I've tried .str.replace and .str.strip with no success. Currently my code looks like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.tsv', sep='\t')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ' ","")
```

When I print the df the column is still shown as `Parents' favorite color` with the apostrophe. Assuming I need to do something different in the replace statement, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: you have an extra whitespace, remove it and it should work

Comment: Look at your code: the string you're trying to replace is `space apostrophe space`, not merely a single apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("'"," ")
```